# Detect empty XML root element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am reading in a bunch of XML files. If the file only contains an empty root element like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root />
```

I want to skip over it. Currently I do:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 
xml = ET.parse(filename)
if not [el for el in xml.getroot()]:
    # skip
```

Is there a better way to handle this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the list comprehension, use the DOM methods `ElementTree` gives you:

```
if not xml.getroot().getchildren(): 
    # skip
```